# What is the best way performance wise to create an object while parsing in ANTLR4?

Tags: performance, parsing, grammar, antlr4

I'm parsing a message and creating an custom object Message while doing the parsing. I was wondering Performance wise, is it better to create the object in the parser actions or elsewhere?

for now I'm overriding the exit rule methods.

```
parser.addParseListener(new MessageGrammarBaseListener(){
            MessageType message = null;

            @Override
            public void exitStartofMessage(StartofMessageContext ctx) {
                message = new MessageType();
            }

            @Override
                public void exitPersonalInformation( PersonalInformationContext ctx) {
                    Person p = new Person();
                    p.setName(ctx.name.getText());
                    message.setPersonalInformation(p);

                    }
(...)
});
```

is it better to do it this way or in the parser action ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to separate parsing process and AST bypass, because of parsing can be implemented for different runtimes. Also these actions are different logical steps. So I think you do everything correctly.